# twitter bootstrap btn-navbar only shows one line

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar collapse:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-navbar' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.nav-collapse'>
        <span class="icon-bar"/>
        <span class="icon-bar"/>
        <span class="icon-bar"/>
</button>
```

However I only get a single line on the actual bar. Is there a way I can fix this?[image]

Comment: try `a` element and not `button` - like so `<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">` I don't know if this is the problem or not, have you altered the default bootstrap file past colours? You are not showing us a live example or any of your CSS

Comment: Tried it. No difference.

Comment: well as it stands you really need to provide a live example (http://jsfiddle.net) or show us the CSS code that element is using for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<button type="button" class='btn btn-navbar' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.nav-collapse'>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

The *span* tag is not a single tag. If you don't close it properly, the browser interprets it as:

```
<span class="icon-bar">
  <span class="icon-bar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Which is why you were only getting one bar.

Comment: What did you do differently? Your markup is the same as in the question, except for adjusted indentation. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: How odd... I messed up there, and I've updated my answer. I must have copy/pasted the wrong lines from my editor. Anyways, the trick is that <span> tags are not single tags, they require a separate closing tag because they are intended to wrap content.